# What is EF Templated Code Generation used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-generation

I've seen several [examples](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/19/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4---templated-code-generation.aspx) / tutorials of using Entity Framework with Templated Code Generation.

What is this tool doing? Is creating a new DataContext and a new set of EntityObjects? or is replacing the old ones? Why you will use a Code Generation instead of working directly with the ones created by the designer?

Comment: The "code generated by the designer" actually uses a default T4 template to generate the entities/context, the benefit to using a custom template is if you have specific needs for you data objects (special methods, attributes, properties, omit navigation properties, inherit types, etc.) there is a lot that could be written on this but it is all use-case specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an explicit template you can modify the template to customize your entities.

One common customization is to make all entities inherit from a common base class.